# Simple goalseek cycle used to work, but not anymore

Tags: excel, vba

I have used this simple goalseek cycle in the past, it always worked. Basically, it runs goalseek for every cell in a column.
I tried using it today, and I got "run-time error 1004". I cannot figure out what is wrong. This simple macro still works in the old spreadsheet, but it does not work in a new one I just made. I tried changing range, changing file, nothing. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub goalcicle()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Range("P13:P112").Cells
    Cell.GoalSeek 0, Cell.Offset(0, 7)
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Since it works in the original spreadsheet but not the new spreadsheet, it would be helpful if you could post them along with the question. It's likely that some difference between the sheets is causing the problem.

Comment: Yup, I would like to see the contents of the cells. 1004 just means application defined error, so it's likely that Excel is throwing the error based upon the contents or set up of the sheet. Check that the cell 7 columns across from target contains a formula linked to target cell, as I understand that GoalSeek relies on the existing formulas in the cells to search for the value.

Comment: Thank you, indeed there was no formula in column P, it was in column W (i.e. offset(P..,0,7))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Goal Seek](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-goal-seek-to-find-the-result-you-want-by-adjusting-an-input-value-HP010342990.aspx) requires that you start with a formula.

Make sure all cells in the range `Range("P13:P112").Cells`  have formulas in them

Comment: It was a silly mistake: I was trying to set to zero the cells in column P by changing the cells in offset (0,7) while I should have done the opposite. Indeed, column P did not have formulas. So the code had nothing wrong per se, i was using it the wrong way. Thank you.